# Spark RDD create on s3 file

Tags: java, amazon-s3, apache-spark

I'm trying to create JAVARDD on s3 file but not able to create rdd.Can someone help me to solve this problem.

**Code :**

```
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(appName).setMaster("local");
            JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

    javaSparkContext.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId",
                    accessKey);
            javaSparkContext.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey",
                    secretKey);
            javaSparkContext.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3.impl",
                    "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem");

JavaRDD<String> rawData = sparkContext
                    .textFile("s3://mybucket/sample.txt");
```

**This code throwing exception**

```
2015-05-06 18:58:57 WARN  LoadSnappy:46 - Snappy native library not loaded
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Expected scheme-specific part at index 3: s3:
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.initialize(Path.java:148)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:126)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.globPathsLevel(FileSystem.java:1084)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.globPathsLevel(FileSystem.java:1087)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.globPathsLevel(FileSystem.java:1087)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.globPathsLevel(FileSystem.java:1087)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.globPathsLevel(FileSystem.java:1087)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.globStatusInternal(FileSystem.java:1023)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.globStatus(FileSystem.java:987)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:177)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:208)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.take(RDD.scala:1156)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.first(RDD.scala:1189)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.first(JavaRDDLike.scala:477)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD.first(JavaRDD.scala:32)
    at com.cignifi.DataExplorationValidation.processFile(DataExplorationValidation.java:148)
    at com.cignifi.DataExplorationValidation.main(DataExplorationValidation.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:569)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Expected scheme-specific part at index 3: s3:
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2829)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.failExpecting(URI.java:2835)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3038)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:753)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.initialize(Path.java:145)
    ... 36 more
```

**Some more details**

Spark version 1.3.0.

Running in local mode using spark-submit.

I tried this thing on local  and EC2 instance ,In both case I'm getting same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `s3n://` instead of `s3://`

See **External Datasets** in [Spark Programming Guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#external-datasets)